# setting netcdf4 int variable to np.ma.masked does not work consistently

Tags: python, netcdf4

When I try to set a range in a netCDF4 int variable to np.ma.masked, it's set to -9223372036854775808 and the fill_value gets changed. When I do the same for an index, it behaves correctly. What's going on?! Python 3.8.10, netCDF4 1.6.2.

```
    from netCDF4 import Dataset
    import numpy as np
    nc=Dataset('temp.nc','w')
    nc.createDimension('x',3)
```

> <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'x', size = 3

```
    nc.createVariable('x', int,'x')
```

> <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
> int64 x(x)
> unlimited dimensions:
> current shape = (3,)
> filling on, default _FillValue of -9223372036854775806 used

```
    nc['x'][:]
```

> masked_array(data=[--, --, --], mask=[ True,  True,  True], fill_value=-9223372036854775806, dtype=int64)

```
    nc['x'][:]=np.ma.masked
    nc['x'][:]
```

> masked_array(data=[-9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808], mask=False, fill_value=999999)

```
    nc['x'][0]=np.ma.masked
    nc['x'][:]
```

> masked_array(data=[--, -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808], mask=[ True, False, False], fill_value=-9223372036854775806)

```
    nc['x'][:2]=np.ma.masked
    nc['x'][:]
```

> masked_array(data=[-9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808], mask=False, fill_value=999999)